# Why my Auto hot key script doesn't work properly?

Tags: autohotkey

I use AutoHotkey for windows. I want to write a script in order to paste (the text I copied earlier) with middle button click of the mouse to searchbar of the program Oxford dictionary on my computer. and also when the the window of the program is closed, after I clicked middle button of the mouse automatically open the window and do the same thing I wanted( paste the copied word into the searchbar of program). I write this code :

```
MButton::
IfWinExist, Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary
{
   WinActivate
   Click, 182, 133, 2
   Send, ^a{Delete}
   sleep, 100
   Send, ^v{Enter}
}
else
{   
   Run, "E:\dictionary oxford\OALD9.exe"
   WinActivate, Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary
   sleep, 500
   Click, 182, 133, 2
   Send, ^a{Delete}
   sleep, 100
   Send, ^v{Enter}
}   
return
```

When I run the code, it just do the first task I wanted. It paste into the search bar of the Oxford Dictionary when it is open. But when it is closed, after I click middle button of the mouse it just open the program and doesn't paste the word into the searchbar.

Comment: Are you sure of coordinates? `Click, 182, 133, 2`

Comment: Yes, coordinates are right. because it works when program is open. but when it is not open, and I click middle button of the mouse it open the program but immediately click on upper left of the screen and it doesn't even wait for the program to be open

Comment: Are you sure the new window is open and ready?  Try a 5 sec (5000) of sleep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WinWait is your friend.
[Documentation](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinWait.htm)

```
MButton::
IfWinExist, Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary
{
   WinActivate
   Click, 182, 133, 2
   Send, ^a{Delete}
   Sleep, 100
   Send, ^v{Enter}
}
else
{   
   Run, "E:\dictionary oxford\OALD9.exe"
   WinWait, Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary,,4
   WinActivate, Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary
   Sleep, 500
   Click, 182, 133, 2
   Send, ^a{Delete}
   Sleep, 100
   Send, ^v{Enter}
}   
return
```

Edit: You might want to consider RunWait, also. [Documentation](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/RunWait.htm)

Comment: This worked! It is amazing to see you solved the issue without seeing it in action. Thank you very much for your help :D

Comment: `RunWait` could not be used, it waits for the program to finish (exit) and that's not going to happen here.